# How can I use, If cursor is empty in a SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite, is-empty

Normally, this code works very well. But, if the `cursor` is empty, there is an error in `main.class`. I tried a lot of things. But, I didn't get success. Please help to solve this.

---- database.class ---

```
public List<Integer> count_a() {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String selectQuery = "select book, count(date) from myTAB WHERE (date>'" + 0 + "') group by book"; 

    // if result is empty, there is an error in main.class.
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

---- main.class ----

```
private void load_data() {
    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());

    List<Integer> co_a = db.count_a(); // error is here

    Integer[] co_b = new Integer[co_a.size()];
    co_b = co_a.toArray(co_b);

    List_Row adapter = new List_Row(this, co_b);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvStat);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: use try catch in yor code..

Comment: @User6829548; Try catch will only hide the problem, but the problem remains nonetheless

Comment: just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not a custom `ArrayAdapter` / `BaseAdapter` / whatever

Comment: Sorry, try catch didn't work. SimpleCursorAdapter ok ! but, the error is before setAdapter. The problem is I can't use null/empty cursor data, I know but, I have to find a way. Thank you.

Comment: just pass the `Cursor` you get from `rawQuery` to your `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor

Comment: Ok, but how can I "do-while" loop. Could you please write an example on my codes.

Comment: what loop? just pass the `Cursor` to the `SCA` constructor

Comment: Sorry pskink, I didn't understand. Please show me an example.